# Is SQLite useful for THIS purpose?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've written a multi-threaded bot in Python that uses requests.

I want to read and write the output to a file at the same time. You can think of it like an endless loop.

Through research I found out that you can lock and unlock files for other threads. But it doesn't seem to work on Windows, e.g. the `fcntl` module.

So I'm looking for alternatives. I've never created a database so I'm wondering if SQLite would be suitable for my purpose? That I can read and write the content at the same time without loosing data? :)

Comment: Try to use to save data to mongodb or postgresql for example. It's not so difficult as seems.

Comment: Yeah did it to SQLite working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough the question may be a bit vague, I'll try to answer it anyway.

As **SQLite** is a **transactional Database** which complies to the ***ACID*** principles:

1. Atomicity
2. Consistency
3. Isolation
4. Durability

I don't see a reason why it should not work in your use case.

You should read up on the mentioned principles, as there is an abundance of resources available for doing so I won't bother trying to reformulate the definitions here and will provide corresponding URLs instead.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID
https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html